# Version control system for the centeralized source base

Tags: git, version-control

I was using `Git` for my project but now I am in a componay where all the team members work on same src code files

i.e all the source code is saved on Server and every developer directly uses the code directory ( no local copies ).

Is there still a possibility to use any Version controll system?

Comment: `svn` is a centralized version control system.

Comment: How would you expect to work?

Answer (score 0):

If all the source code is on server and every team member directly access (read/write/delete) it, then you are not using a version control system at first place.
SVN is a centralized. You don't maintain entire repository as your local copy. You have to "checkout" individual branch/trunk and "commit" it to server.

Answer (score 0):

You may use SVN as centralized versioning system, but I would recommend GIT. All the more since the other developers are apparently agnostic of such a system. GIT has nicely documented development workflow (http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/).